# Dropdown-toggle should be a link as well

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I have set up a dropdown toggle with BS4. The dropdown slides down nicely on hover. But now the product owner wants to have the toggle button as a clickable link (in my sample: href="https://www.yahoo.com). But I don't know how to achieve this. Is there a solution for this? Or is it easier to re-build the toggle menu to something else, to have a link seperated from a sliding div (or whatever) afterwards?

Here is my toggle, what I have so far:

```css
html {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 7px;
}
.dropdown.show {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
.dropdown a::before {
  content: "";
}
.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px 7px;
}
.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle::after {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  content: ">";
  color: Orange;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle:active {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle:hover:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  min-width: initial;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 7px;
  font-size: initial;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  display: block;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu a.dropdown-item {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu a.dropdown-item:hover {
  color: Orange;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-toggle {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.dropdown-menu:hover + a:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub3</a>
  </div>
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="http://www.yahoo.com" data-toggle="dropdown">
    MAIN
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

The use of bootstrap's attribute and class was blocking this. i.e, `data-toggle="dropdown"` and `.dropdown-toggle` since they're tied to the framework.

In addition to `pointer-events: none`.

```css
html {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 7px;
}
.dropdown.show {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
.dropdown a::before {
  content: "";
}
.dropdown a.cc-dropdown-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
 
}
.dropdown a.cc-dropdown-toggle::after {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  content: ">";
  color: Orange;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  transition: 0.5s;
  display:inline-block;
}
.dropdown a.cc-dropdown-toggle:hover:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  min-width: initial;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 7px;
  font-size: initial;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  display: block;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu a.dropdown-item {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu a.dropdown-item:hover {
  color: Orange;
}
.dropdown:hover .cc-dropdown-toggle {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.dropdown-menu:hover + a:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<html>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sub3</a>
    </div>
    <a class="cc-dropdown-toggle" href="http://www.yahoo.com">
      MAIN
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh no, sorry to say, but.. this seems to be a missunderstanding! The toggle should happen on mouseover, as it is at the moment. But IN ADDITION the toggle anchor itself should be clickable as well ... :-} Pls see my sample I have a href="https://www.yahoo.com" on the toggle. On mouse over: toggle the submenu. On Click: go to yahoo. Is that possible??

Comment: @JonSnow Ah, sorry i misunderstood. See my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you my friend, great relief!